# Почему не компилируются css и js?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, docker, npm

Пытаюсь разобраться с подключением bootstrap к laravel и уже голову себе сломал, ничего не работает, объясните что я делаю не так, пожалуйста.

И так, все вводные:

Я пытаюсь пересесть с OPServer'a на docker (не знаю, полезна ли эта информация, я пока в этом слишком плаваю) и вдовесок к этому хочу подключить к проекту laravel bootstrap. Проект я кое-как создал, хотя и не понял, почему у меня в нём сразу не было файла webpack.mix.js.
Сейчас файл есть, вот его содержание:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
      require('postcss-import'),
      require('tailwindcss'),
   ]);
```

файлы app.css и app.js в папке resources выглядят так:

```
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

и так, соответственно:

```
import 'bootstrap';
```

Собственно дальше я в командной строке прописываю следующие команды:

устанавливаю зависимости:
npm install

проверяю, что всё установлено:
npm bootstrap (-v9.5.1)

пытаюсь провести сборку:
npm run dev

в результате получаю это:

```
>npm run dev

> dev
> vite


  VITE v4.3.8  ready in 408 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
  LARAVEL v9.52.7  plugin v0.7.8

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost
```

запускается сервер, но файлы не компилируются и в папке public не появляется никаких папок.

Буду очень благодарен, если объясните, на каком моменте мой гениальный план по становлению кодером, юзающим docker и bootstrap потерпел крах.

Comment: С 8 (или 9) версии Laravel ушёл от Mix и перебрался на Vite
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite

Comment: @lezhni благодарю, теперь всё работает